# I am doing more and fewer in toggle class, text was changing (more option to fewer) when i clicked but down arrow and up arrow was not coming

Tags: jquery, html, css

I will attach my code below,

I am creating downarrow in this b tag

when i clicked more option (text is not changing to fewer and up arrow and down arrow both coming in same time. I want  when i click more option (it should change to fewer option) and in more option down arrow should indicate and in fewer option up arrow should indicate, i have attached a css above,

Can u give any hint to solve this problem?? Thank you

Jquery code

```
$(".toggle_container").hide();
        $("a.reveal").on('click', function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("fast");
            if ($.trim($(this).innerHTML()) === '<span>More Option</span><b></b>') {
                $(this).innerHTML('<span>Fewer Option</span><b></b>');
            } else {
                $(this).innerHTML('<span>More Option</span><b></b>');
            }
            return false;
        });
```

Html code:

```
<a class="flLeft reveal" id="changeText" href="javascript:;">          
        <span>More Option</span><b></b>
    </a>
```

Css code:

```
.reveal.active b,.reveal b{
  border-bottom: 6px solid #fdbd43;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  bottom: 6px;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 0;
}
.reveal b {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: 6px solid #fdbd43;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
HTML code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="moreLessButton collapsibleTrigger">
      <span class="show">MORE</span>
      <span class="hide">LESS</span>
</a>
```

JS code:

```
function CreateCollapsibleTrigger() {
    $(".collapsibleTrigger").click(function (e) {
        // set active classes to the trigger buttons
        $(this).toggleClass("activeTrigger");
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    CreateCollapsibleTrigger();
});
```

CSS code:

```
.moreLessButton {
    background: url('../../images/arrow-down.png') right no-repeat;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 100%;
    outline: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 1px 15px 1px 3px;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #58585a;
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

    .moreLessButton:hover {
        background: url('../../images/arrow-down-hover.png') right no-repeat;
        color: #6BB1BD;
    }

    .moreLessButton.activeTrigger {
        background: url('../../images/arrow-up.png') right no-repeat;
    }

        .moreLessButton.activeTrigger:hover {
            background: url('../../images/arrow-up-hover.png') right no-repeat;
        }

    .moreLessButton .hide {
        display: none;
    }

    .moreLessButton.activeTrigger .show {
        display: none;
    }

    .moreLessButton.activeTrigger .hide {
        display: inline;
    }
```